# Lists flowing to side

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

How can I get a list to flow to the side?

The best example ive seen of what I mean is on [TruTower's VoIP Page](http://www.trutower.com/voip/). I'm trying to update my site from old html to new css but cant find the right code.

Prefer OL style (numbers) but UL is okay too.

Comment: Do you mean just a horizontal list?

Comment: Yes, which list on the page you're referring to ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Sorry. Horizontal list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at this jsfiddle for an example to get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/ashrobbins/SKzwU/

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    float:left;
}
li + li {
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
}
a {
    display:block;
    padding:7px 10px;

    color:#222;
    background:#eee;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#666;
}
a:active {
    color:#fff;
    background:#0090cf;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I'll give that a try. Just change the UL part to OL if I want to change between the two I assume?

Comment: In addition to Andrew's answer, this is what you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/SKzwU/33/ . I have edited his fiddle.

Comment: Okay cool! Is there a way to make the numbers horizonal with the content or no?

Comment: Actually I'm not even seeing them now, but they weren't a bit ago, at least not in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Updating Andrew's answer to suit your needs exactly:

Screenshot:

[image]

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
ol {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
    background: #eee;
}
li {
    float:left;
    padding-left:5px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
li + li {
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
}
a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:7px 10px;

    color:#222;
    background:#eee;
    text-decoration:none;
}

li:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#666;
}
a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#666;
}
a:active {
    color:#fff;
    background:#0090cf;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SKzwU/35/)

Comment: Okay I'll try this one instead, but it appears to work the first way. I'll just try both and see which one I like :)